# Applying "dim" function over elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list

I have `n` number of lists, lets say `list1`, `list2`, ..., `listn`. Each list has 10 elements and I need to calculate the "mean" of "dim" of ten elements of each list. So the output should be a vector of length `n`.

For example the first element of the output vector should be:

```
n1 = mean(dim(list1[[1]]), dim(list1[[2]]), dim(list1[[3]]), ..., dim(list1[[10]])
```

I know how to obtain it using `for`-loops but I am sure it is not the best solution.

The lists have structure derived from one of "Bioconductor" R packages called "edgeR".
So each element of the list has this structure:

```
 $ :Formal class 'TopTags' [package "edgeR"] with 1 slots
  .. ..@ .Data:List of 4
  .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':      2608 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. .. .. ..$ logFC : num [1:2608] 6.37 -6.48 -5.72 -5.6 -4.01 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ logCPM: num [1:2608] 5.1 2.55 2.08 1.57 3.08 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ PValue: num [1:2608] 3.16e-292 1.57e-187 2.15e-152 5.58e-141 1.27e-135 ...
  .. .. .. ..$ FDR   : num [1:2608] 7.37e-288 1.83e-183 1.67e-148 3.25e-137 5.92e-132 ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr "BH"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "healthy" "cancerous"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "exact"
```

And since each list has 10 elements, I have 10 repeats of above structure when running:

```
str(list1)
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of `list1` (`str(list1)`)

Comment: How do you suppose to use a `for` loop to iterate over *variables* `list1`..`list10`?

Comment: @SimonO101 I added the edits above

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks alot. One more question then I wouldnt ask anything regarding sapply any more. How about if I wanted to calculate the mean of dim of corresponding elements from "list*"s. like this: n1 = mean(dim(list1[[1]], list2[[1]], list3[[1]], ...,listn[[1]])) and then n10 = mean(dim(list1[[10]], list2[[10]], ..., listn[[10]]))

Comment: @hora I am not sure I understand. Can you include  a`dput` of your data structure

Comment: I think you are looking for `mapply`

Comment: @SimonO101 Sorry that I did not explain well. Actually the dataset is quiet huge. I can send the RData file if it is necessary. But, what i meant is that in your answer, using sapply, we calculate the mean of dim of {1..10} elements of each list. Now, how about calculating mean of dim of first element of all lists. Then calculating the mean of dim of second elements of all lists, etc. Should I use mapply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your objects are called `"list*"` and you have *no other* objects with the names `list` in them, you can easily stick all the lists into a single list object which will make it easier to operate on them...

```
ll <- mget( ls( pattern = "list" ) )
sapply( ll , function(x) mean( sapply( x , dim ) )
```

Answer (score 5):

### Original question

[`lapply`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) (or `sapply`) is your friend:

```
mean(sapply(mylist,dim))
```

If you have many lists with a uniform meaning and structure, you should use instead a list of lists (i.e., `mylist[[3]]` instead of `mylist3`).

### Edited question

```
sapply(mylist, function(x) mean(sapply(x,dim)))
```

will return a vector of means of inner lists.

### Question in a comment

If your list contains matrices instead of vectors and you want to average one of the dimensions (`dim(.)[1]` or `dim(.)[2]`), you can use [`ncol` and `nrow`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nrow.html) for that instead of [`dim`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dim.html).

Alternatively, you can pass any function there, e.g.,

```
sapply(mylist, function(x) mean(sapply(x, function(y) sum(dim(y)))))
```

to average the sums of dimensions.

Comment: Yes but I have n lists. Should I use "for" loop again for repeating the above command for all of them?

Comment: Yes, But I have lists of lists. So I already have: list3[[1]], list3[[2]], ..., list3[[10]]. And then I have n lists of type list3

Comment: one more question: how about if I need to calculate the mean of first element of "dim" function like: mean(dim(l1)[1],dim(l2)[1],...)

Comment: use `function(x) dim(x)[1]` instead of `dim` in `sapply`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have not used nested "apply" before. And I think I have to use first line of code by SimonO101, as I should have some replacement for word "list" in your command :sapply(list, function(x) mean(sapply(list, function(x) sum(dim(x))))). Yes?

Comment: the word `list` is just a name for your variable, I think I was not very consistent there - fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution using `Map` function where mylist is the list of yours:

```
Map(function(x) mean(x[[1]]:x[[10]]), mylist)
```

Example:

```
a<-list(1,2,3,4)
b<-list(2,3,5,6)
mylist<-list(a,b)



k<- Map(function(x) mean(x[[1]]:x[[4]]), mylist)
>k
[[1]]
[1] 2.5

[[2]]
[1] 4
```

To convert to vector:

```
> do.call(rbind,k)
     [,1]
[1,]  2.5
[2,]  4.0
```

OR,

```
library(plyr)
ldply(k)
   V1
1 2.5
2 4.0
```

If the elements of each list are matrix:

```
Map(function(x) mean(dim(x[[1]])[1]:dim(x[[10]])[1]), mylist)
```